# Android Alpha Animation Very Slow

Tags: java, android

I have an app that show a SurfaceView that shows a camera preview, and on top of that a couple other UI elements (buttons).
Basically, the user inputs their code, i FadeOut the UI leaving the normal preview and take a picture which is later uploaded.
This all worked fine on an older tablet, however, switching to an XPERIA Z2 tablet this thing became VERY SLOW when calling view.animate();
I have noticed that the tablet starts OpenGL, (I didn't notice that on the old tablet).

> : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
>       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.06
>       Build Date: 02/12/14 Wed
>       Local Branch: au090
>       Remote Branch:
>       Local Patches:
>       Reconstruct Branch:

Now this might be the problem. How do I turn it off?
I will paste the animation here anyway:

```
public static Animation fadeOut() {

    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);

    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //add this

    fadeOut.setDuration(500);

    return fadeOut;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if anyone expiriences something like this, the problem was I was setting the animation on the view and then calling view.animate(). 
Using view.startAnimation(Animation) is working allright!